Google scraped an unpublished, not publicly available, currently under review manuscript: can I post it to arXiv?
I have a paper currently under review (mathematics). I didn't post is to arXiv, but I'm now thinking that I probably should since Google's AI search app is now bringing it up. I had the article uploaded to our university server and listed on my website as a paper under review, but not actually publicly linked to anywhere. I didn't really know that such files would get scraped up by search bots, but in hindsight it makes sense that they do. The only reason I know this is because I received an email about the paper from someone who I don't know. Either they know the reviewer and gained access that way, or they somehow found it through online search.
My question is as to what to do:
(1) just go ahead and upload it to arXiv,
(2) contact the journal to ask permission to upload it to arXiv (and to check review status), or
(3) do nothing and just wait to hear back from the journal?
My thought is that the most ethical course is to upload a preprint before submission, but after submission it feels like there is an implicit agreement with the publisher to abide by whatever their rules are (hence my thought to email the editor to ask).
It's also a short paper and straightforward work that should not be difficult to review, in case that helps give advice--the review process should be completed soon anyhow if going by typical review times for this journal.

By now, all of the journals I interact with have discovered that preprints exist and have made some sort of policy about preprints, usually clearly stated in their instructions to authors. It shouldn't be necessary to ask the editor unless you're requesting to deviate from the policy. Have you checked?

What has Google made public? Just a reference or the full article?

@Buffy I googled the article title after getting a random email about it, and the google search AI thing (you know like how every google search gives AI results up top now) brought up a summary of the article and a link to my manuscript (posted on my university server, like my personal website, but not actually hyperlinked from anywhere).

@BryanKrause I just check the publisher website and it seems to indicate I can share preprints however I please, but I just want to be careful.

Well, if robots can find it so can humans. Just with more difficulty. So don’t post stuff you don’t want public.

Depending on the journal's policies uploading it yourself without permission might cause problems. Some permit it, others don't. So yes, contact the editor before you take any action. Their website might give their policy, also.
I suspect that you will have permission, especially in math, where preprints are now generally acceptable to math journals.

This is what I am leaning towards, contacting the journal editor just to be safe.

Good idea. I think it would be a rare math journal that didn't ok it. But their rules are their rules.

You do not need to do anything you wouldn’t have done anyway if Google hadn’t scraped your paper. In particular, there is no ethical imperative to share your paper on arXiv before you feel ready to do so.
If you want to upload your paper to arXiv and it’s under review, you would want to check that this is permissible according to the journal’s policy. Whether the journal is okay with submissions that are uploaded to preprint servers (whether they are uploaded after or before submission, I’m pretty sure it makes no different) is usually stated on the journal’s website. For mathematics journals, the answer is universally Yes AFAIK. If you can’t find the answer online, you can contact the editor to ask.
Anyway, doing nothing is a perfectly acceptable option.
